# What is the so funny in Annie words after tasting Grape wine?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Movie *The Parent Trap*, Annie say this words to her mother Elizabeth.

> Well, if you ask me, the bouquet's a little too robust for a Merlot,
>   but then again I'm partial to the softer California grape.

[The Parent Trap](http://www.cswap.com/1998/The_Parent_Trap/cap/uk/25fps/a/01_07), 1:08:07

to this words her mother Elizabeth laughs.

**Background**: Annie & Hallie switch their places at school picnic after realizing divorced parents are same for them, Then Annie goes to Nick (Father staying at USA) as Hallie & Hallie goes to her Elizabeth (Mother staying at london) as Annie.

Comment: I haven't watched the whole thing before and I don't know this scene, but I think it's because they had been surprised (and probably a little disbelieving) that she had known anything about wine, much less comment on it. Meanwhile, it's funny (dramatic irony) for the audience because we know that she's the other twin who *does* know about wine and knows how to comment on it.

Comment: *much less that she had been able to comment on it.

Comment: To add on to @TeacherKSHuang's good answer, generally it's pretty amusing to see children acting like adults. Few children know anything about wine, let alone the different varieties. It's the kind of thing only adults really know for the most part. That factor along with the precociousness of the child to actually make that wine comment would make it amusing to a lot of adults. It's much like seeing children in doctor's uniforms or superhero outfits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it was the real Annie who said this or was it Hallie posing as Annie?  I have only seen the original, not the remake with Lindsey Lohan.

The mother would have found this funny because her actual daughter, Annie, being raised in London would not know so much about wines, whereas the twin sister Hallie was raised on a California vineyard. Thus the inside joke to the audience:

> partial to the softer California grape.

Her Mom might have also realized that the twin sister was from California, and it would have crossed her mind "How does she know all that?" and the producers may have used it as a way to foretell what was to come, while propagating the stereotype of brash, outspoken Americans versus the more reserved English.